# How to return the SUM of a COUNT in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Scenario:** I am trying to build a query that will return the SUM of a COUNT.
**Purpose of the Query:** I need to identify all of our Participants that are currently listed on 2 or more Positions.

**Current Query:**

```
select pa.firstname, pa.lastname, pos.name as "POSITION", count(pos.name) as "POSITION COUNT"

from cs_participant pa, cs_position pos

where pa.payeeseq = pos.payeeseq
and pa.firstname like '%DEV%'
and pa.lastname like '%TEST%'

group by pa.firstname, pa.lastname, pos.name
```

**Results:**
[image]

I need to SUM the POSITION COUNT and somehow return only FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, and SUM. So, if a Participant is currently on 2 or more Positions, the query would return the Participant's FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, and SUM of POSITIONS.
If I could also return the POSITION in the far column without creating duplicate rows for each unique POSITION, that would be a huge help!
For example, a Participant with 2 POSITIONS would return the Participant's FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SUM OF POSITIONS, and POSITION_1 on the first row, while the second row would have blank values for the Participant's FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, and SUM of POSITIONS, but return POSITION_2 in the 4th column (Similar to a "break" function in Web Intelligence).

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want to probably store position in a separate joint_table?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `HAVING`, not `SUM`.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select pa.firstname, pa.lastname, count(*) as "POSITION COUNT"
from cs_participant pa join
     cs_position pos
     on pa.payeeseq = pos.payeeseq
group by pa.firstname, pa.lastname
having count(*) >= 2;
```

I removed the `where` conditions, because it is not clear what those are for.  You can, of course, put them back in if they are relevant to your query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon -- The `having` clause seems to be pulling me closer. However, the count values are higher than they should be. For example, one Participant in particular returned as having a Position Count of 6, when they actually have a Position Count of 2. I'm assuming there might be some duplication occurring, but I'm not sure of the cause. This is a vendor database, so the scheme is unfamiliar to me. Any ideas off the top? Otherwise, I might need to speak with our vendor. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, check this out. The inner SQL is quite the same as you have in your question. I wrapped it in another SQL to get the sum:

```
select firstname, lastname, sum(position_count)
  from (select pa.firstname firstname,
               pa.lastname lastname,
               pos.name as position,
               count(pos.name) as position_count
          from cs_participant pa, cs_position pos
         where pa.payeeseq = pos.payeeseq
           and pa.firstname like '%DEV%'
           and pa.lastname like '%TEST%'
         group by pa.firstname, pa.lastname, pos.name)
 group by firstname, lastname
 having sum(position_count) >= 2;
```

The result is:

```
FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME             SUM(POSITION_COUNT)
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------
DEV                  TEST                                   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @PT_STAR -- Your query is working, but I'm retrieving inflated values for position_count SUM. I'm finding out that there are additional fields in the Position table accounting for duplication. I will have to solve that through our vendor.

Answer (score 0):

This query uses analytic functions to return the first name, last name, position and (total) position count for each participant. It uses row_number to only print the first and last name once per participant (and leaves it blank for rows after the 1st row).

```
select
    case when rn = 1 then firstname else '' end firstname,
    case when rn = 1 then lastname else '' end lastname,
    name as "POSITION",
    position_count as "POSITION COUNT"
from (
    select pa.firstname, pa.lastname, pos.name,
    count(*) over (partition by pa.firstname, pa.lastname) position_count,
    row_number() over (partition by pa.firstname, pa.lastname order by pos.name) rn
    from cs_participant pa
    join cs_position pos on pa.payeeseq = pos.payeeseq
) t1 where position_count > 1
order by firstname, lastname, rn
```